# Convert a Math Equation to output as a float value

Tags: c#

So I have this line of code:

```
var maths = anInteger / keyprice;
```

I print it this line:

```
textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + "Converted into: " + maths;
```

I was wondering how do I make it output a float, say I have `anInteger = 42` and `keyprice = 24` into a 2dp number?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C# the result of dividing 2 integers is an integer. If you want it a `float` then cast one of them into a `float`:

```
var maths = anInteger / (float)keyprice;
textBox1.Text = $"{textBox1.Text} Converted into: {maths.ToString("n2")}";
```

If prior to C# 6.0 then:

```
var maths = anInteger / (float)keyprice;
textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + "Converted into: " + maths.ToString("n2");
```

Comment: I am not the downvoter, and I really don't understand why people are doing this without explaining, but I guess it's "dividing" not "deviding"

Comment: @meJustAndrew - it was a spelling mistake that I've corrected :)

Comment: I guess the downvote was for using console instead of textbox

Comment: @meJustAndrew - haha we think the same :) I just updated it to use the textBox :)

Comment: @Samuel Stubbings - Did this help you solve the issue?